# Settings for local and meteor.com subdomain deployment

Tags: meteor

I can't seem to find documentation of how to accomplish this. I'm requiring Facebook login and deploying to a meteor.com subdomain. I would like to have a settings.json file (or some other way) of recognizing the environment and providing the correct FB App configuration details.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `process.env` variable to see what's your environment and swith between settings. For example, the `provess.env.ROOT_URL` to bring `http://localhost:3000` as a result.

See the node js docs [here](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env)